# Fetch value from database in textbox

Tags: c#, sql, casting, combobox

This is my code

```
 sc.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Cust_id from Cust_master where Cust_id = '"+cidshow.SelectedItem+"' " , sc);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataReader sdr;
        sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            cid.Text = sdr.GetInt32(0).ToString();

        }
```

Actually there is a combobox in my form which holds the value of customer id. I just want to fetch the value from database to a textfield involving the same combo box.. but it gives this error in my code.

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Data.DataRowView' to data type int.

Comment: what datatype is Cust_id?

Comment: Cust_id is obviously int. You need to use the right column of your DataRowView. Instead of `cidshow.SelectedItem` use `(int)cidshow.SelectedItem.Item[0]` or whatever column you want to use.

Comment: ElGauchooo, it doesn't works like that.

Comment: try to remove the `'` something like, Cust_id = "+ cidshow.SelectedItem, sc);

Comment: just simply tell me how to get a value of combo box and show it in a text field.

Comment: Why are you using `ExecuteNonQuery()` when you are querying the database?

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteNonQuery()` returns the number of rows affected, so once you work out your issues, you still are not going to have the value you are looking for.

You need to be using `ExecuteReader()`, which will return your query result. 
See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You should be able to do something like:

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Cust_id from Cust_master where Cust_id = '"+cidshow.SelectedItem+"' " , sc);
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        cid.Text = reader[0].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Thanx Mattm.. but I found another way to do that. :)

Comment: Does the underlying database driver support parameterisation? The SQL concatenation looks a bit risky here, even if `cidshow.SelectedItem` can only be an integer.